# how to build simple program run from terminal in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, c++, qt5

I'm writing simple program in c++ using netbeans. I want it should be executable thru ubuntu terminal as other do

like "php samel.php" it works
I want something like this

please guide me how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, save your code in form of a file. Let's say the file name is xyz.c
Open the terminal and change the directory to the location where your file is(use cd command). 
After that compile as `g++ xyz.c`
This will compile your code. Doing that will produce an executable file a.out, which you can run by typing `./a.out`

Comment: no I want something advance like we install other doing apt-get install myprogram